# :validates using logical comparisons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table with a couple of boolean columns.

A PurchaseOrder needs to be marked as complete (first boolean), before it is invoiced (the second boolean).

I'd appreciate some pointers as to how to validate legal combinations of these booleans.

What I have in mind is something like,

```
:validates (!:complete and !:invoiced) or (:complete && :invoiced) or (:complete && !:invoiced)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Only tangentially related to your question, but I'm sure you'd be better off using a state machine if you aren't already: http://www.shopify.com/technology/3383012-why-developers-should-be-force-fed-state-machines

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've a background in real-time programming, so I'm familiar with the value of state-machines and use them elsewhere in my Application, but wasn't aware of this gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your PurchaseOrder goes through several states during its life cycle, like a [finite-state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine).

One thing we use in production systems is [acts_as_state_machine](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_state_machine), to help accomplish this behavior.

It allows you to define:

- a series of states that an object can be in
- the events that move the object between states
- and finally which states you can move between, and which states you can't move between. For example, you might want to allow your PurchaseOrder to be go from complete->to->invoiced, but not backwards from invoiced->to->complete. [acts_as_state_machine](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_state_machine) allows you to set this up in a declarative style.

[acts_as_state_machine](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/acts_as_state_machine) will allow you to define those complex behaviors. Reading it takes a bit of time to understand it, but for systems like these, it has been a life saver.

Comment: Sure thing. Might prove useful in more complex situations.